# numpy 3D-image array to 2D

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, slice

I have a **3D-numpy** array of a gray image, which looks something like this:

```
[[[120,120,120],[67,67,67]]...]
```

Obviously I have every R G and B the same because it is a gray image - this is redundent.
I want to get a new 2D array which looks like:

```
[[120,67]...]
```

Which means to take every pixel's array [x,x,x] to just the value x

How can I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the shape of your `ndarray` is (M, N, 3), then you can get an (M, N) gray-scale image like this:

```
>>> gray = img[:,:,0]
```