# Numpy 2D image to 3D

Tags: python, numpy

I have a greyscale image represented as 2D numpy array and want to make it a 3D numpy array representing a color rgb image (which is obviously still grey).

```html
img.shape       // (100, 100)
img[10, 10]     // e.g. 42

// do something

img.shape       // (100, 100, 3)
img[10, 10]     // e.g. [42, 42, 42]
```

I found this question which asked the opposite:
[numpy 3D-image array to 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365029/numpy-3d-image-array-to-2d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Numpy's `dstack()` to stack three grey images depthwise:

```
RGB = np.dstack((grey, grey, grey))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an opencv function for this: `image_color = cv2.cvtColor(image_gray, colorcode)`.

See the available colorcodes in documentation https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html

The right one for you could be `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB`.

```
import cv2
image_color = cv2.cvtColor(image_gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

That would give you the grayscale image as 3 channel rgb array.

Using numpy you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40119878/14997346

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code help?

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.zeros((4,4),dtype='int64')
aa[1,1] = 42
aa = aa.reshape((4,4,1))
bb = np.broadcast_to(aa,(4,4,3))
print(bb[1,1,:])
```